# Bad permissions for Gerrit Administrator

Tags: gerrit

I have a Gerrit system were my user is part of the Administrators group but I can't view a review I just created for a newer project. I believe the projected worked in 2.7 but I just upgraded to 2.8.1.
I'm assuming that if I'm part of the Administrator group I should be able to view anything especially something I created.
I can view and change information in other projects. The Access page of the problem project looks similar to the ones that work.
What can I look at to see what's causing the issue?

Is there a problem with projects with the directory structure like **test/widget**?

Comment: Perhaps a problem with Apache's AllowEncodedSlashes? See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/NAeOX6janm8.

Comment: I'd point you to that page in order to resolve the same problem as expected by Magnus: http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/ReleaseNotes/ReleaseNotes-2.6.html#_reverse_proxy_configuration_changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magnus was correct.
It was totally a config problem because I'm using a proxy. The answer was in the release notes for 2.8.0. It only looked and acted like a permissions problem. I updated my apache config and now everything works fine. Updates in **bold**

**AllowEncodedSlashes On**

`ProxyPass /r/ http://127.0.0.1:8081/r/` **nocanon**